# Arduino Uno rejects uploads, changes ports

Tags: serial-port, arduino, microcontroller, avr

After experimenting with some Serial communication (which may or may not be relevant), the Arduino IDE throws a "Error opening serial port" error when I try to upload new code to the Arduino or use Serial Monitor. This has happened in both Windows and Linux.

In Linux, after a failed upload I tried disconnecting, then reconnecting the board. It was reassigned to the next open serial port. For example, it starts out as /dev/ttyACM0, then moves to /dev/ttyACM1, and so on.

When plugged in, the "TX" LED lights up, then goes dark. When I try to upload to it, the "TX" LED flickers twice, then nothing.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open the file **~/.arduino/preferences.txt** file(linux). There you will find a string **serial.debug_rate**. Check its value. Typically its value is **9600**(it denotes the baud rate of the serial communication). So if this value is something else, that might be causing the problem.

I have no definite answer for what might cause the value to change. But in my case changing it back to 9600 worked fine.

Comment: Changing serial.debug_rate back to 9600 worked! I forgot that changing the baud rate in Linux has weird effects...

Answer (score 0):

Having something physically plugged into the serial port on the arduino will keep sketches from uploading.